# Why does my C++ ZeroMQ subscriber not receive any data?

Tags: python, c++, zeromq

My (Python) publisher:

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
connectStr = "tcp://*:%d" % 5563
socket.bind(connectStr)

messageNum = 0
while True:
    ++messageNum
    message = "Testing %d"%messageNum
    print("Sending.. '%s'"%message)
    socket.send_string(message)
    time.sleep(1)
    messageNum += 1
```

My (C++) subscriber (running in GTest):

```
TEST(ZeroMqPubSubTest, SubscribeGetsData)
{

    // Set up the subscriber we'll use to receive the message.
    zmq::context_t context;
    zmq::socket_t subscriber(context, ZMQ_SUB);
    // Connect to the publisher
    subscriber.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5563");
    subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ""); // Set the filter blank so we receive everything

    zmq::message_t response(0);
    EXPECT_TRUE(subscriber.recv(&response));
}
```

I start up the publisher then start up the subscriber. The latter never returns though.

If I run a Python subscriber doing (I thought) exactly the same thing..

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect ("tcp://127.0.0.1:5563")
socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

print ("Waiting for data...")
while True:
    message = socket.recv()
    print ("Got some data:",message)
```

..it works fine:

> Waiting for data...
>
> Got some data: b'Testing 8'
>
> Got some data: b'Testing 9'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two overloads of `setsockopt` defined in [`zmq.hpp`](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp#L543):

```
 template<typename T> void setsockopt(int option_, T const& optval)
 {
     setsockopt(option_, &optval, sizeof(T) );
 }

 inline void setsockopt (int option_, const void *optval_, size_t optvallen_)
 {
     int rc = zmq_setsockopt (ptr, option_, optval_, optvallen_);
     if (rc != 0)
         throw error_t ();
 }
```

By providing only two arguments you implicity used the first overload, which assumes a value length of `sizeof(T)`. This resolves to one, because `""` is a zero-terminated character array. To pass in an empty string you need to use the second overload and specify a length of 0:

```
subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
```

Alternatively, use a zero size data type:

```
char none[0];
subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, none);
```

Comment: Spot on @kazemakase. I'm still learning the subtleties with ZeroMQ and it seems there are a few aspects of the cpp interface in particular that have a couple of gotcha's.